# Disable python chrome driver extensions without lose driver path

Tags: python, selenium

I started having issues running a python script which uses selenium and chrome driver, so I want to disable extensions of chrome driver using python without losing the path where the driver is located.

Currently I have the below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

path_to_Ie = 'C:\\Python34\\ChromeDriver\\ChromeDriver.exe' 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_Ie)
url = 'https://wwww.test.com/'
browser.get(url)
```

and I would like to add the below lines:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Any idea how I can merge both codes to make it work properly?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just provide multiple keyword arguments:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_Ie, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```