# Python disable Chrome Extension

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I try to use Python to log in a web, type in use id and password, and download some files. however, before logging the page, there is a error msg says

> "Failed to load extension from
>   C:\User\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir12188_17478\internal. Loading
>   of unpacked extensions is disabled by administrator"

. After I hit "Enter", the rest goes well.

I have searched here, and find one post is related to my question, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226305/disable-python-chrome-driver-extensions-without-lose-driver-path). But the code is still not working for me. the pop up error windows is still showing up. Any ideas or suggestion is highly welcome. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
import time
import urllib3
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driverpath = 'C:\\Users\\xyz\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\chromedriver.exe'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath, chrome_options=chrome_options)
url ='https://userid:password@weblink'
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: Looks like [Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator](//stackoverflow.com/q/43571119)

Comment: are you using it on company laptop with restricted permission. https://kite.com/python/docs/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options

Comment: @wOxxOm, yes it helps, downgrade to chrome drive 2.27 helps. Thank you!

Comment: @cibin yep, company laptop with restriction